# Maximum call size exceeded when running setter

Tags: javascript, class, object, setter, p5.js

I'm coding a version of a board game for a personal project with p5.js being my way of outputting graphics. I have a class that's making objects that correspond to spaces on my board. These squares need to be colored, so I have a setter that should let me change the colors, but when this is run it gives me `Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

I've tried renaming the variables and the setter to fix a naming issue and that wasn't it. The program also throws an error when I turn the setter into a method.

```js
const gridSpace = class {
  constructor(x, y, num, color) {
    this._posX = x;
    this._posY = y;
    this._num = num;
    this.color = color;
  }
  
  get color() {
    return this.color;
  }
  set color(color) {
    this.color = color;
    this.draw();
  }
}

const space35 = new gridSpace(1, 2, 3, "blue");
space35.color = "red";
```

I want said space to end up as either a red or blue square when ran, instead of the white that the squares are currently when ran.

Edit: I'm adding a link to the online p5.js editor so it's easier to see the problem. The sizing is a bit inconsistent, so sorry for that.
https://editor.p5js.org/drewhford04/sketches/s6RbWMzpD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These calls: `this.color = "red"` and `space35.color` are calling the *setter* and that *setter* is calling recursively itself.

An alternative is to rename the attribute `color` to `_color` in order to avoid the recursion.

```js
const gridSpace = class {
  constructor(x, y, num, color) {
    this._posX = x;
    this._posY = y;
    this._num = num;
    this._color = color;
  }
  
  get color() {
    return this._color;
  }
  set color(color) {
    this._color = color;
    //this.draw();
  }
}

const space35 = new gridSpace(1, 2, 3, "blue");
console.log(space35.color);
space35.color = "red";
console.log(space35.color);
```

Comment: This was the problem! Can I have a bit more explanation of the recursive calling to make sure it doesn't happen again?

Comment: @x0LandShark0x you are using a getter an setter to define a `color` property. Thus, when you say `this.color = color` it calls the setter to write the `color` property... yet, guess what the setter does? it does exactly the same thing! So, the setter is calling the setter. Instead, in Ele's code, we have `_color`. Notice there is no getter or setter for `_color`. Now, the setter for `color` does not call itself anymore, it sets `_color`. Similarly the getter reads `_color`. No recursion there.